# Word Macro Run-time error '70': Permission denied

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a macro that deletes Charts, MS Tables, Excel copied tables & images in MS Word

```
Sub deleteNoise()
    Dim i As Integer

    With ActiveDocument
        For i = .Tables.Count To 1 Step -1
            .Tables(i).Delete
        Next i
        ActiveDocument.Shapes.SelectAll
        Selection.Delete
    End With
End Sub
```

It worked fine. Until I saved the file and tried to run it, now it only deletes tables and when it gets to an image I get the following error.

> Run-time error '70': Permission denied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was the `With` statement was rubbish.

```
Sub deleteNoise()
Dim objPic As InlineShape
For Each objPic In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
objPic.Delete
Next objPic
    Dim tbl As Table
    For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
        tbl.Delete
    Next tbl
        Dim shp As Shape
ActiveDocument.Shapes.SelectAll
        Selection.Delete
End Sub
```